# ms compact framework change button to image

Tags: c#, compact-framework

I am searching how in ms compact framework 3.5 change Submit button to image. I want to use image as button in my windows mobile application with CF 3.5 but i can not find any usefull information.

Can someone give some howto or tell what to do?

Comment: There is a submit button in CF 3.5?  Are you sure you don't mean just a Button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard button does not have a way to add an image so you have to create a control yourself.  Check out [How to Create a Microsoft .NET Compact Framework-based Image Button](http://web.archive.org/web/20160217041555/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446518.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Download a sample of an `ImageButton` from [Microsoft Download Center](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17697) It's an `msi` file, install it, note the install path, after installed browse to it and you will find a `VS` solution (sample).